# Do I need a database to install Joomla on localhost using XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, installation

I downloaded Joomla to create a website, but before buying any domain/hosting service, I prefer to work locally.

Then, I downloaded XAMPP and moved joomla's file to XAMPP's htdocs folder.

From localhost domain, I started joomla installation. At a certain point, **I'm requested to insert data for accessing database.**

Actually, my site needs no database. My questions are:

- Is it necessary to specify a database's data during Joomla's configuration?
- Should I install MySQL on my PC and use its access data during configuration of joomla, while working locally?
- If answer to previous question is YES, can I change access data any time to fulfill hosting service requirements, once my site is uploaded to "real server?

Comment: What do you plan to use Joomla for? If you want to store articles on it or have registered users you probably have to use a database for that. Also XAMPP should be bunlded with MySQL which you can fire up from the XAMPP Control Panel - and access by localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: `Actually, my site needs no database`....wrong. Joomla requires a database to work as this is where data is saved.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes you require a database for Joomla to work.
2. Xampp comes with mysql, just make sure mysql server is running and create a
   database using phpmyadmin.
3. You can change your access data
   anytime either by editing configuration.php or by changing global
   configuration settings by logging in as joomla admin.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, the database is required for Joomla to work. XAMPP installs with a MySQL server. As long as both Apache and MySQL are running as services, the database will be created automatically during Joomla installation (just add "root" as database user, and leave the password field empty).

When you move your site to a hosting service, I highly recommend using [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html), as it creates a simple file containing both your Joomla files and your database. If you then use [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) to restore the backup on your server, you'll be asked to provide the database details again (note that you'll have to create the database manually through the hosting's control panel first, as most hosts don't allow you to create databases "on the fly".)

If you prefer to upload your Joomla files and database manually, you can change the database settings in the file `configuration.php` found in the main directory of Joomla. The fields you should edit are:

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = '';

public $log_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla/tmp';
```

(the order of the fields may vary). More details can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_website_from_localhost_to_a_remote_host).

Answer (score -1):

You may find that some of xampp's default settings need to be changed.  If you have difficulty installing Joomla or installing extensions into it then [Joomla on localhost](http://www.weblinksonline.co.uk/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/install-joomla-localhost.html) may be of use.

Xampp like other localhosts comes with default settings that do not suit Joomla or Wordpress

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of does Joomla need a database to be installed.  @ubisum us under the impression his site doesn't need a database.  If he wants to run it on Joomla, he is mistaken.

Comment: By virtue of the fact it points to the settings for the database the yes (by inference) it does.

Comment: Perhaps I should have spelt it out?
'Yes a database is needed and here is a link to the settings needed'.